# $P(X \geq 2Y) = ?$ where $P(n) = 2^{-n} , n =1,2,3,...$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

Let $X,Y$ are independent identically distributed random variables.Then $P(X \geq 2Y) = ?$ where $P(n) = 2^{-n} , n =1,2,3,...$.

So it is the discrete case, So in order to calculate this -

$P(X \geq 2Y) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \sum_{x = 2y}^{\infty} 2^{-x-y} = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}2^{-y} (\frac{2^{-2y}}{1 - 2^{-2}}) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}  \frac{4}{3}. 2^{-3y} =\frac{4}{3}. \frac{2^{-3}}{1 - 2^{-3}} = \frac{4}{21}.$

Is the above correct?

Comment: What do we answer if your answer is correct?

Comment: :) Actually I had done probability a long time back, trying to capture it y doing some problems and some has no answers so trying to match it up with other potential users.Thanks!

Comment: Why would you ask a question that is potentially unanswerable?

Comment: @KennyLau the question is "is the above correct?" you say "yes" or "no". I don't see why is that "unanswerable"?

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer is not Correct. It should be

$P(X \geq 2Y) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \sum_{x = 2y}^{\infty} 2^{-x-y}
 = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}2^{-y} (\frac{2^{-2y}}{1 - 2^{-1}}) 
 = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}  \frac{2}{1}. 2^{-3y} =\frac{2}{1}. \frac{2^{-3}}{1 - 2^{-3}}
 = \frac{2}{7} $